# Multiple MySQL instances for different users in the same machine

Tags: php, mysql

We have a VPS that we use as Git central server for our repositories and also we use it to test our web apps.
Currently we are using a single database instance for multiple users which is not handy, we want to make multiple MySQL instances so that every user have his own mysql instance that is independent from others.

I found that I have to use the `mysqld_multi` program but I failed to make it work...
I'm searching for a good tutorial for this or any other solution.

The VPS is under Debian v7

Comment: You use one MySQL daemon (`mysqld`) where you have the option to add multiple users and multiple databases. I really have no idea at what point someone thought that it'd be great, cool or even useful having multiple daemons when you already have all the tools you need in the single daemon.

Comment: I'm not expert in MySQL, if you know to get al clean separate mysql for each user so please tell me how.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how isolated you want each user to be, it might be easier to use a single instance of MySQL, and have each user have a different account and database within it.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql

Comment: but this will make a problem if different users want to make the same database name

Comment: So don't let them make the database with the same name. It's super easy. Look at how google doesn't allow the same email for different people. There's nothing wrong with telling someone they can't have their database named any way they like.

Comment: I want to let each user make his own choice on the name of the database. What I want to get is like Shared hosting, every one has his own MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching and trying, I came across a great article that solves my problem: [MySQL multiple instances on Ubuntu (which works on Debian too)](https://naveensnayak.wordpress.com/2013/11/10/mysql-multiple-instances-on-ubuntu/)